# BackboneJS with XML ajax

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, backbone.js

this is a two part question from a JS newbie.

So, I was trying to create a backbone application using requireJS by following [Thomas Davis's tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/).

1. How do I go create Backbone collections out of an ajax call to a server that provides data in XML? collections.fetch() seem to be expecting a JSON backend.
2. while trying some things, I ended up with the following code, in which the page doesn't refresh upon populating the collection "bookStore" from within Ajax success-callback.

   Here is how far I have gotten so far.

   ```
   var bookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
       el: $("#books"),
       initialize: function () {
           thisView = this;
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "books.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   $(data).find('book').each(function (index) {
                       var bookTitle = $(this).find('name').text();
                       bookStore.add({ title: bookTitle });

                       console.log(seid);
                   });
                   thisView.collection = bookStore;
                   thisView.collection.bind('add', thisView.tryBind);

               }
           }).done(function (msg) {
               alert("Data retrieved: " + msg);
           });

           this.collection = bookStore;
           this.collection.bind("add", this.exampleBind);
           this.collection.bind("refresh", function () { thisView.render(); });
           /*
           // This one works!
           bookStore.add({ name: "book1" });
           bookStore.add({ name: "book2" });
           bookStore.add({ name: "book3" });
           */
       },
       tryBind: function (model) {
           console.log(model);
       },
       render: function () {
           var data = {
               books: this.collection.models,
           };
           var compiledTemplate = _.template(bookListTemplate, data);
           $("#books").html(compiledTemplate);
       }
   });
   ```

Here, the success call-back in the "initialize" function seems to be processing the data properly and adding to the collection. However, the page doesn't refreshed.

While I was stepping through the Firebug console, the page gets refreshed however. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. You can override the default `parse` function to provide XML support. It should return the data transformed into JSON http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse
2. Bind the render to a `reset` event instead of `refresh` for Backbone<1.0 or to a `sync` event for Backbone>=1.0

It could look like this

```js
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book,
    url: "books.xml",

    parse: function (data) {
        var $xml = $(data);

        return $xml.find('book').map(function () {
            var bookTitle = $(this).find('name').text();
            return {title: bookTitle};
        }).get();
    },

    fetch: function (options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.dataType = "xml";
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }
});

var bookListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
    }
});

var bks = new Books();
new bookListView({collection: bks});
bks.fetch();
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/ULK7q/73/

Comment: One additional question. Should I be performing the fetch from the Router code? If I do that, everytime I visit, including the browser-back button the code ends up fetching the collection from the server all over again.

Comment: You probably could instantiate the list in you init code and pass it to your router, not tying the fetch to the routes. Note that the recommanded way is to bootstrap your app with serialized JSON in your page. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap