# Fetching data from xml using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm not able to fetch data from xml using backbone.js. No proper example is given on the sites I checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [BackboneJS with XML ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419061/backbonejs-with-xml-ajax)

Basically, you need to overwrite the model/collection's `parse` method to build an object form the XML response.

In addition, you need to overwrite the requested data type, as it is json by default.